# regular expression to match name with only one spaces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string condition in js where i have to check whether name entered in text box contains with one space only.

```
 pattern: name.status === 'full_name' ? /^[a-zA-Z.+-.']+\s+[a-zA-Z.+-. ']+$/ : /^[a-zA-Z.+-. ']+$/
```

But the above regex matches names ending with 2 spaces also.

I need to match it such that the entered name should accept only one space for a name string. So the name will have only one space in between or at the end.

Comment: So, did you fix the issue in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Two observations: 1) `\s+` in your pattern matches 1 or more whitespaces, and 2) `[+-.]` matches 4 chars: `+`, `,`, `-` and `.`, it is thus best to put the hyphen at the end of the character class.

You may use

```
/^[a-zA-Z.+'-]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z.+'-]+)*\s?$/
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6KqdSR/1)

**Details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[a-zA-Z.+'-]+` - 1 or more letters, `.`, `+`, `'` or `-`
- `(?:\s[a-zA-Z.+'-]+)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\s` - a single whitespace
  - `[a-zA-Z.+'-]+` - 1 or more letters, `.`, `+`, `'` or `-` chars
- `\s?` - an optional whitespace
- `$` - end of string.

Note:  if the "names" cannot contain `.` and `+`, just remove these symbols from your character classes.

Comment: This is not passing if i give full name ending with one space. Need to accept name which accepts only one space in the middle or end. Also not matching names with 2 strings.

Comment: @rubyist So, there can be 2 whitespaces?

Comment: Yes. I mean to say for a name string maximum 1 space is allowed. So "Alex" with space, "Alex Christop" with space and "Alex Christop David" with space are all ok.

Comment: I think you want to match a string of 1 word or 2 words, with 1 whitespace if there are 2 words between them. Use [`^[a-zA-Z.+'-]+(?:\s[a-zA-Z.+'-]+)?$`](https://regex101.com/r/YBu5dO/3) then.

Comment: I need to match a name string that can accept 1 space.So "Alex" with space, "Alex Christop" with space and "Alex Christop David" with space are all ok. Here each name string has only 1 space in the between or end of the name.

Comment: But `"Alex"` has no space.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151361/discussion-between-rubyist-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 0):

```
/^\S+\s\S+$/
```

try this

Some explanations:

- ^  - start of string
- \s - single whitespace
- \S - everything except whitespace
- "+"- quantifier "one or more"
- $  - end of string

Comment: If there is no `\n` in this values, this is not a problem (but yes, matching line breaks); so use something like `/^[^ \t]+[ \t][^ \t]+$/` for example

Answer (score 0):

you could also use word boundaries...

```js
function isFullName(s) {
  
  return /^\b\w+\b \b\w+\b$/.test(s);
}



['Giuseppe', 'Mandato', 'Giuseppe Mandato']
  .forEach(item => console.log(`isFullName ${item} ? ${isFullName(item)}`))
```